# Manually updating rows in AngularJS ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using AngularJS ui grid. I have a requirement when on clicking a drop-down in the HeaderCellTemplate i want to get the displayed rows (visible rows) and update a cell with a value and set those rows to dirty mode to enabling saving. Can anyone guide me on the steps?

Regard,
Brian Noronha

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna only a Guide HowTo then check this Steps.
 1. DropDown Filter => http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering
 2. Editing a Row => http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable
 3. Save/setDirty => check Number 205 then // Sorry not allowed to post more as 2 links

I hope it Helps.